# Android Camera Activity like Instagram

Tags: android, camera

Which are the best ways to create a Camera Custom activity, using FRONT FACE CAMERA or BACK FACE, and choosing the best sizes of SurfaceView and Camera for each device?

I would want to create an activity like Instagram has, squared and with custom layouts above and below.

If there's any sample that's like this, please It would be very useful.

Answer (score 0):

see https://thenewcircle.com/s/post/39/using__the_camera_api (small) or https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera (with lots of enhancements)

Comment: This library is discontinued and deprecated. can you  anyone suggest anything else?

Comment: @AlexCohn Commonsguy library will no longer available as free in future. Please try to use other libraries to fulfill this feature.

Answer (score 0):

you can try my simple library https://github.com/mistreckless/PortraitCameraSupport
 but instagram developers did that by another way. They capture the entire screen image then programmatically cut the square preview you see